# Iphone - Multiple images stored as Album Art in Media Items

Tags: objective-c, ios, media, artwork

Suppose mp3 files that have multiple images saved as album art in a user's music library.
Retrieving the MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork from the media item in IOS seems to only retrieve a single image. Is it possible to get the collection of images out of the meta data? Do all the images even make it into the device (iphone/ipad) or are extraneous images stripped out and only one of the images makes it through the transfer?
Here is a link to what itunes displays for one of these types of file:

http://www.djfx.us/imagebin/MultipleArtwork.png

Many thanks to the contributors of this forum!

Rgds,
Felipe